# Why an extra println statement is necessary for printing Akka future contents

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, future

I am trying to run a hello world Akka future program and running it in Intellij idea, below is the code

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {
  val future = Future {
    "a" + "World"
  }
  future foreach println
  println("extra")
}
```

In above code if I remove

```
println("extra")
```

Why Future contents are not shown in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futures gets executed in separate threads. Your main thread could finish it's work before future's thread. Try to sleep on main thread to see the result in console

Comment: Avoid sleep. Use something like `System.in.read()` so you can terminate the application with pressing a key.